# Lalitha Devi, Gayatri, Durga and Raja Rajeshwari, are they different forms of Parvathi?

Tags: devi, parvati

There is Lalitha Sahasranama. Then there is Gayantri Mantra chanted everyday. Then there is Durga widely worshipped in Bengal and other areas. Raja Rajeshwari is widely worshipped mostly i southern parts if India. Do they all represent different forms of Parvathi?

Comment: I think it will be helpful if you go thru the following couple of answers. 1-https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20742/4732 2-https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20765/4732