# What was the name of the form of Devi before Lalitha Devi?

Tags: devi, goddess, lalita

After the death of manmadha for continuity of world devi herself took the bow and arrow and bow of manmadha and took a new form called Lalitha devi. What was the before form name of the form of Devi  before Lalitha devi?

Comment: You asked a same question with exactly same title [Difference between Bhuvaneshwari and Lalita devi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21830/difference-between-bhuvaneswari-and-lalitha-Devi). Use a better title as this question is different.