# Which of the Dasha Mahavidyas are associated with each day of Navrathri?

Tags: dasha-mahavidya, navrathri

In what order do the Dasha Mahavidyas correspond to each day of Navrathri?

Comment: Nava Durgas are associated Mahavidyas aren't.

Comment: @Rickross Indeed, Navadurgas are the more popular forms of the goddess associated with this occasion. However, [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29463/is-there-a-connection-between-the-navadurga-and-the-dashmahavidya?rq=1) seems to suggest in the question itself that the Mahavidyas too are associated in a lesser known tradition.