# Maa Tara Tarapith prayers and chants in Sanskrit

Tags: worship, devi, prayer, tara

[image]

i would like to ask if someone knows some chants or prayers to worship Tarapith Maa Tara , if possible transliterated into english (not translated).

Thank you in advance

Comment: You want any Stotrams of Goddess Tara? Few Stotras are given in Brihat Tantrasara.

Comment: @Rickross i was searching the commonly used in Tarapith .

Comment: Stotrams of Goddess Tara are only found in Tantras. I can give such Stotrams but it will be a hard task for me because I have to type the entire Stotra manually (so no copy paste).. And, in Tarapith temple they use mantras for the worship of the Goddess.

Comment: Only Mantras? I see. So maybe you can point me to a transliterated reference online?

Comment: I have not seen any online reference so far. Will have to check.

Comment: @Rickross do what you can no worries

Comment: Thanks .. I have answered now with some basic information. You may find it useful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Goddess TArA is the 2nd MahAvidyA. (IMO the following answer will be helpful for you to read: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20742/4732)

Stotras are found mainly in PurAnas/ItihAsas and in Tantras. In case of TArA, the Stotras are only found in Tantras. Goddess TArA's worship is entirely based on Tantras, unlike say that of Goddess DurgA, which is a mixture of Tantrik and PurAnik methods.

In [Brihatantra-sArah](http://www.shivashakti.com/tantrasara.htm), we find three Stotras given for Goddess TArA.

1. TArAshtakam (from Brihan-Nila Tantram) 2. TArA Kavacham (from Rudra YAmala) 3. TrAilokya Mohana TArA Kavacham (from Shri TArA Kalpa).

Among these, the first one is quite short (comparatively) and I am giving only this Stotra in full. Typing manually these Stotras is quite a tedious job and the last two Stotras are quite long. So, I am not giving them here. Also only transliteration is given not translation.

> atha tAra-stotram ||
>
> MAtar-nila-sarswati pranamatAm soubhAgya-sampatprade
> pratyAlira-padasthithe shava-hrudi-smerAnanAmbhoruhe |
>
> Phullendi-varalochana-traya-yute kartrim kapAlotpale khadga
> anchadadhati tvameva sharanam tvAmishvari mAshraye ||
> VAchAmishvari bhakta-kalpa-latike sarvArtha-siddhisvari
> gadya-prAkrita-padya-jata-rachanA-sArvagya-siddhiprade |
> Nilendi-varalochana-trayayute kArunya-vArAm nidhe
> soubhAgya-amrita-varshanena kripaya sincha tvamsmAdrisham || 2
> Kharve garva-samuha-purita-tano sarpAdi-veshojjvale
> vyaghra-tvak-parivita-sundara-kati-vyAdhuta-ghantAnkite |
>  Sadyah
> kritta-galadrajah-parimilan-mundadvayi-murdhaja-granthi-shreni-nrimunda-dAmalalite
> bhime bhayam nashaya || 3
>   mAyAnanga-vikAra-rupa-lalanA
> vindvardha-chandrAnkite hum-phat-kAramayi tvameva sharanam mantrAtmike
> mAdrishah |
>  Murtiste janani tridhA sughatitA sthulAti-sukshmA parA
> vedAnAm nahi gocharA kathamapi prAptAm nutA-mAshraye || 4
> Tvat-pAdAmbuja-sevayA sukriti-nogacchati sAyujya-tvAm tasya shri
> parameswari trinayan-bramhAdi-sAmyAtmanah |
>  SamsArAmbu-dhimarjane
> patu-tanun devendra-muukhyAn surAn mAtas-tvat-pada-sevane hi vimukhAn
> kim mandadhih sevate || 5
> mAtas-tvat-pada-pankajadvaya-rajo-mudrAnkoti-vinaste devajaya-sangare
> vijayino nishanka-sankegatAh |
>  Devo-haham bhuvanena me sama-iti
> spardhAm vahastah paraistvat-tulyAm niyatam yathA shuchi-vari-nAsham
> vrajanti swayam || 6
>  TvannAm-smaranAt palayanparA drashtuncha
> shaktAnate bhuta-preta-pishAcha-rAkshasa-ganA yakshAshcha nagadhipah
> |
>  DaityA dAnava-pungAshcha khacharA-vyAghrAdikA-jantavo dAkinyah
> kupitAnta-kAshcha manujam mAtah kshanah bhutale ||7
>  Lakshmih
> siddha-ganashcha pAduka-mukhAh siddhAs-tathA vairinAm
> stambhashchAgnira-nAngane gaja-ghatAstambha-stathA mohanam |
> MAtas-tat-pada-sevayA khalu nrinAm sidhyanti te te gunAh krAntih
> kAnta-mano-bhavasya bhavati kshudrahap vachaspatih || 8
> TArAshtakamidam punyam bhaktimAna yah pathen-naraha |
> PrAtar-madhyAnha-kAle cha sAyanhe niyatah shuchih |
>  Labhate
> kavitAm divyAm sarva-shastrArtha-vid-bhavet | 
> Lakshi-manashvarAm
> prApya bhuktvA bhogAn yathepsitAm |
>  Kirti kAntishcha vairuhyam
> sarveyAm priyatAm vrajet VikhyAtinchApi lokeshu prapyAnte
> moksha-mApnuyAt |
>
> Iti nila-tantre tArAshtakam samAptam ||

(Note: The Stotram ends with 8, the remaining portion states the Phalashruti. Also, I have not followed any particular transliteration scheme here, only where there is Dhirga-A-kAra, I have mentioned that with a "A".)

For completing a PujA of any deity one just needs it's DhyAna mantra, AvAhana mantra, pujA mantra etc.

We can get these details from any PujA-Paddhati books. I am quoting from Anhika KrityAm by Shri ShyAmA Charan Kaviratna VAridhi (aka ShyAmA Charan SharmA); 1st BhAga; 1st Khanda; DhyAna-mAlA section; pp 135-136.

> **DhyAnam of Goddess TArA:**
>
> PratyAlida-padAm ghorAm munda-mAlA-vibhushitAm |
>  KharvAm
> lambodarim bhimAm vyAghra-charma-AvritAm katau ||
> Nava-Yauvana-sampannAm pancha-mudrA-vibhushitAm |
>  ChaturbhujAm
> lola-jihvAm mahAbhimAm vara-pradAm ||
> Khadga-katrika-samAyukta-savyetara-bhujadvayAm |
> KripAnotpal-samyukta-savyapAni-yugAnvitAm ||
>  PingogrAi-ekajatAm
> dhyAyenmaulA-vakshyabhya-bhushitAm |
> BAlArka-mandalAkAra-lochana-traya-bhushitAm ||
> JalacchitA-madhyagatAm ghora-damshtrAm karAlinim |
>
> SwAvesha-smeravadanAm stryalankAra-vibhushitAm ||
> Vishva-vyApaka-toyAntah sveta-padma-upari-stithAm |
>
> **PujA Mantra:** Om tArAyai namaha;
>
> **AvAhana Mantra:** Om tAre devi iha gaccha iha gaccha, iha tishtha iha tishtha, iha sannidehi iha sannidehi, iha sanniruddhasva, atrAdhishthAnam kuru, mama pujAm grihAna ||

> **Vija Mantra:** Strim;
>
> **Mula-Mantra:**  Hrim strim hum phat.
>
> **GAyatri Mantra:** Om tArAyai vidmahe, mahogrAyai dhimahi | tanno devi prachodayAth ||

Comment: Thank You! 

Comment: You are welcome @LuckyPashu