# Is it true that the following goddesses are mentioned as Mahavidyas?

Tags: tantra, shaktism, dasha-mahavidya

I found the following goddesses mentioned as Mahavidyas in wisdomlib.

These goddesses are Chandeshvari, Laghusyama, Triputa, Vanadurga, Shulini, Ashvarudha, Trilokyavijaya, Mahavarahi and Annapurna. But, is it true these goddesses are mentioned as Mahavidyas?

Comment: Not sure of these ones precisely, but my understanding is that there are several different lists & groups of MahaVidya goddesses, with different devi, and also different numbers of goddesses. I think the ten most commonly referred is just a more popular list, more widespread & known, from what I was taught.

Comment: See this answer --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20742/4732

Comment: I knew now Devi Annapurna is the Mahavidya. But, what about others ?

Comment: In some texts the others are also mentioned as Mahavidyas too but the 10 ones are the most prominent ones.@VHIYOMANSHANMUGANATHANMoe