# Who is dhumavati? How can one worship her in common household?

Tags: worship, dasha-mahavidya, bhakti-worship, dhumavati

What are the benefits of worshipping dhumavati mahavidya? Can it be done in any common household? Also is there any Bhakti ways of doing it?

She appears to be sort of similar to alakshmi so why should anyone worship her because no one wants bad health , Weald and bad luck in their life . Please clarify all the doubts and misconceptions about this goddess.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20587/4732